# I am trying to get excel to pull data from one sheet and list it on another sheet if certain criteria are met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Essentially, here is what I'm wanting and don't know how to do it. I want a formula, or a function that will do the following.

IF A1<>"Vacant" AND B1="x" THEN add text from A1 to List1

The purpose of this is to then generate a list of names that can be copied to a separate worksheet. Here's what I'm doing. I have created a staffing pattern that has days off marked. I want a function that will compile a list of names for people that are off on a given day, denoted by column B through H. I also need it to disregard any names that are listed as "Vacant" because those spots need to stay, but aren't filled at the moment. Once I have that list compiled, I then need to have excel use that list to fill in a column on the shift roster for people that are regularly off.

After talking in the comments and coming a long way in my understanding of what I'm trying to do, I still am at an impasse.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried changing the references in the code I was given, but it's not giving me any output, and I'm not fluent enough in VBA to know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim nameRange As Range, entry As Range

Set nameRange = Worksheets("Staffing Pattern").Range(Range("A7"), Range("A21").End(xlUp))

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Sunday").Range("F81:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ""
    For Each entry In nameRange
        If UCase(entry.Value) <> "VACANT" And UCase(entry.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "X" Then
        Worksheets("Sunday").Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Value
        End If
    Next entry
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I ended up using a combination of both of the answers provided with a little google ingenuity. I used the Power Queries to do exactly what I wanted to do, then used VBA to write macros and linked them to buttons on the pages. The macros only refresh two of the Power Queries at a time, so the system won't crash, and there is a button on each shift roster. Thanks for everyone's help in solving this!

Code I used for the macros:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Refresh Sunday
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
Dim con As WorkbookConnection
Dim Cname As String

For Each con In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If Left(con.Name, 11) = "Query - Sun" Then
    Cname = con.Name
        With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Cname).OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = False  'or true, up to you
            .Refresh
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Each macro was then changed to apply to each day of the week, and a button was linked to it. It works perfectly!

Comment: This can be done with formulas and be dynamic, but it isn't a pretty sight.  You prepopulate a range with formula, each of which adds another qualifying value to the list.  But it also needs to keep track of where you're looking in the source list and previous results.  The formulas can be monsters.  Sometimes it simplifies things using some helper columns.  I don't have enough time (or coffee) to tackle this now, but maybe some other readers would be willing to give it a shot.  You'll get a better response, though, if you expand the question with some sample data.

Comment: You want it dynamic, but if you only need to update it once or twice a day, a simple workaround might be to use filters on the source data.  Force the filter to recalculate and copy and paste the result.

Comment: Should've made it more edit-friendly, sorry. I tried your code, and it outputs in `F2` and nothing else. The reason for this being the line ` Worksheets("Sunday").Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5)` Here the "F" and the "5" should be the same column. But the 5 also refers to the current sheet. Try: `Worksheets("Sunday").Range("F" & Worksheets("Sunday").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Value`

Comment: Edited with solution used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use "Power Query": select your input range, go to the **Data** ribbon  and choose **From Table/Range**.  Then use the Filter buttons on each column header to apply your criteria:

- Column1 ... Text Filters ... Does not equal ... Vacant
- Column2 ... Text Filters ... Equals ... x

Then right-click Column2 and choose **Remove Columns**. Then hit the **Close & Load** button to generate a new table with the result, on a new Worksheet.  You can tweak the Close & Load options on the way through.

In the future just hit the **Refresh** button on the **Data** ribbon to refresh the output table.

Comment: This gives me a manual representation of the data I'm looking for, and I thank you for that, but I need this to be dynamic and update automatically as the information is changed in the Staffing Pattern. Is there a way of making this method do this?

Comment: From the Data ribbon, hit Queries & Connections. Then right click that Query in the pane and choose Properties. You can set Refresh every 1 minute, and Refresh when opening the file.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I then used the formula `=IF('Back End'!A2<>"",'Back End'!A2,"")` to call the data that was generated by the Power Query. This worked perfect, and gave me a dragable formula to expand my results and give me a list on another sheet. Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, it worked until I put it into practice. Apparently Excel doesn't really like refreshing 14 Power Queries all at the same time... I think I'm going to have do do this in VBA.

Comment: In VBA you can run the refresh using QueryTable.Refresh

Comment: It's not the implementation, I think it's the computer not being able to handle 14 Power Queries at the same time. Our computers at work are not the most powerful by any stretch of the imagination...

Comment: So record a Macro running the Refresh one-by-one. It will generate QueryTable.Refresh statements that dont run every query in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have a function adding something to a list, as a function only dictates what is to be shown in that specific cell.
What you can do, is populate the list with functions so that it can fill  itself. Or use a macro.
It's a lot easier to make exactly what you want with some visual representation, but you can write the function you described as:

```
=IF(A1<>"Vacant",IF(B1="x",A1,""),"")
```

VBA stuff:

First off, when you want macros to run automatically, you can put them in the worksheet. Just right click the sheet to get there, or just select the sheet in the VBA editor.

`Worksheet_Change` is a useful function to run a macro each time something changes.
Usually accompanied by a range restriction that looks something like:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then
```

This to have it run only when changes occur in a range where we want to check.

You could do something like:

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim nameRange As Range, entry As Range

Set nameRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A65000").End(xlUp))

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ""
    For Each entry In nameRange
        If UCase(entry.Value) <> "VACANT" And UCase(entry.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "X" Then
        Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Value
        End If
    Next entry
End If
End Sub
```

To populate Column `E` with values from column `A`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The downside of this method is that we delete and write the list every time there is an update. 
So if we have a very long list, it could get pretty slow.

You can use the same approach to update a Power Query, but using the line:

```vbs
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

With `Sheet2`obviously being the sheet with the PQ.

**Edit**

So, I did some adjustments for editing. Could probably do more, but it kind of depends on how you want to utilize it.

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nameRange As Range, entry As Range, outCol As String, oCN As Long, outSheet As Worksheet

Set nameRange = Worksheets("Staffing Pattern").Range("A7:A21")
Set outSheet = Worksheets("Sunday")
outCol = "F"


oCN = Columns(outCol).Column
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then
    outSheet.Range(outCol & "2:" & outCol & outSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ""
    For Each entry In nameRange
        If UCase(entry.Value) <> "VACANT" And UCase(entry.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "X" Then
        outSheet.Range(outCol & outSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Value
        End If
    Next entry
End If
End Sub
```

Currently, this will clear the entire output Column in the output sheet. Then fill it from output column row 2 and down, with values from nameRange that aren't "vacant" and has got an adjacent X.

If you want to apply this to several positions, you can convert every option you want to change into a variable, and then call it instead. Mainly to not repeat all the code over and over.

*What i mean is something like this:* 
In the sheet with the list being edited, you put something like this:

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "A7:A21", "Sunday", "F")
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "C5:C40", "Sunday", "H")
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "A7:A21", "Saturday", "F")
End If
End Sub
```

And then in a Module, you put something like this:

```vbs
Public Sub writeList(ByVal inSheet As String, nameRange As String, outSheet As String, outCol As String)
Dim entry As Range, oCN As Long, outS As Worksheet, nRange As Range

Set nRange = Worksheets(inSheet).Range(nameRange)
Set outS = Worksheets(outSheet)
oCN = Columns(outCol).Column

    outS.Range(outCol & "2:" & outCol & outS.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ""
    For Each entry In nRange
        If UCase(entry.Value) <> "VACANT" And UCase(entry.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "X" Then
        outS.Range(outCol & outS.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Value
        End If
    Next entry

End Sub
```

You could just put them under each other in the Sheet code if you like, having it in a Module isn't a requirement. You can put it where ever since it's public.

You can also split the sheet code, so that you don't have to redraw lists that aren't affected by the change. Either with multiple IF's or with else if

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "A7:A21", "Sunday", "F")
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "A7:A21", "Saturday", "F")

ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("C:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Call writeList("Staffing Pattern", "C5:C40", "Sunday", "H")

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand using the functions on the sheet to call data from another sheet, but the issue I'm having there is that I want the list to condense, that way I don't have empty spaces in the list of names that outputs. That way each line has a name on it until all the spots on the staffing pattern have been processed.

Comment: That makes sense, and then this won't work. I guess you could have the first cell in the list search for the first valid entry, and the following rows do the same, but using the previous cell in the list as a starting point. That, or use VBA to populate the list. Or what Mike Honey said, I guess :)

Comment: How would I get excel to search for valid entries like you suggested? Is there a way to have it do that?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I'm not exactly sure how to best write it in a function. It's easy enough with a Macro. But if you are using Macros, you could just use a macro to automatically update the PowerQuery, if that thing can't update automatically.
I need to do a bit of testing.

Comment: I already have one macro written for determining if the text in a cell is bold or not, so macros are already enabled. If this requires a macro as well, I'm gonna need to do some more Visual Basic studying... I'm still relatively novice at this, but I'm a quick learner.

Comment: You could have something like {=INDEX(Table1[Column1],MATCH(FALSE,Table1[Column1]="Vacant",0))} To find the first non Vacant, but then we haven't even checked the other column for x yet, and it gets kind of complicated.

Comment: I may be able to use that. That gives me my first non "Vacant" cell, how would I continue being able to skip over "Vacant" cells?

Comment: I haven't quite figured that part out yet, so I leave you with a VBA approach while I think about it.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was wanting. I have a few clarifying questions though. Can this be used send the data to another sheet in the book? For instance, instead of sending to E on the same sheet, send to Monday!F81? Also, if I'm reading the code right, the first range starts the search at A2, would the second range be the stop at A65000? I'm going to be compiling two lists, one for Supervisors, with a total of 15 positions, and one with Officers, with a total of about 45 positions, so I don't think it will be too cumbersome for the process to rewrite the list every time.

Comment: One more clarifying question. In your example, you have it pull from A and then from B. Can you have it pull from A, and then from C as well? And can these all be written in the same VBA module?

Comment: Even if you won't use this, I still want to clarify. You can absolutely send it to another sheet. By doing worksheets("sheet2").Range....

Comment: Range("A65000").End(xlUp)) searches for the last used cell. It's done from the bottom, in case you have empty cells. So the final range is only the used cells. But you can absolutely set a range. And for the last question, the short answer is yes, absolutely.

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: I'm still not getting it to work. I tried using the new code you gave me in the edit, and I changed the reference for F2 to F81 and it still doesn't work. I don't know what else to do with it.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, since I don't know what you've done and what isn't working. Soon this question will be so many edits it's going to be hard to follow.

Comment: You're right. I don't know if it is going to be able to do what I need it to.

Comment: Well, if you Edit again or start a new question is up to you, but if you could include pictures of what you are doing, and the code you use, I/we can troubleshoot it for you.