# auto-populating multiple lines in spreadsheet from 1 input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have 2 sheets within a workbook and the first sheet has a list similar to this:

[image: Table with 3 columns (Type, Present?, Multiple?)]

Is there a way to auto-populate a list on the second sheet based on the inputs on the first sheet? So if the type is present it will add a new line and if there are multiple it will add that number of lines. Like this:

[image: Table containing 2 banana cells, one grape cell, and 2 orange cells]

If this is possible, would there also be a way to move the rows with the A column as new inputs are added or deleted?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to do with the help of macros. I'm sure it can be done with formulas was well, but that's beyond what I have time for.

So a worksheet_change macro, and I will borrow 90% from [This previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1430554/i-am-trying-to-get-excel-to-pull-data-from-one-sheet-and-list-it-on-another-shee/1430563#1430563).

So in the code of the first sheet (right click the sheet tab and select show code) I put this:

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim inputRange As Range, entry As Range, outSheet As Worksheet, oCN As Long, i As Long, outCol As String

Set inputRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C6")
Set outSheet = Worksheets(2)
outCol = "A"

oCN = Columns(outCol).Column
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), inputRange) Is Nothing Then
    outSheet.Range(outCol & "2:" & outCol & outSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ""
    For Each entry In inputRange

        '--- This is where it's new---

        If UCase(entry.Value) = "X" Then
            For i = 1 To entry.Offset(0, 1).Value
                outSheet.Range(outCol & outSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = entry.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Next i
        End If

        '--- And that's all really ---

    Next entry
End If

End Sub
```

So the process should be, put this in the worksheet with the list, and change the `inputRange` accordingly.
And then outSheet and outCol to where you want it printed (default now is worksheet number 2, cell A2 and down.

There are room for improvements in this, both for a more dynamic code, and a more efficient one. Also error handling and such, but this should be a good start.

[image]